# How to print a custom type with typeof

Tags: typescript, types, typeguards

I want to use `console.log(typeof foo)` to get the type of foo:

```
interface myCustomType {
    flag:boolean
}

let p:myCustomType = {flag:true};

console.log(typeof(p)); // I expect 'MyCustomType', but i get 'object'
```

But I'm getting a `object` instead of `MyCustomType`.

Also, I want to difference between custom types:

```
switch(typeof foo) {
    case 'MyCustomTypeA': /* do domething */ break;
    case 'MyCustomTypeB': /* do domething */ break;
}
```

but it always is 'object'.

Comment: The type system ***does not exist at runtime***. You cannot interact with the compile time type system. Either create something more tangible like a class, or define a custom type guard that will detect an object by its structure, or don't rely on the concrete types. That is usually a code smell and means you're not writing OOP code. You can use polymorphism if it's important for different objects to produce different behaviour.

Comment: Like @VLAZ mentioned, you don't have typescript types at runtime, just javascript. You may be looking for something like a [tagged union type](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/tagged-union-types-in-typescript) and [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing)